# Как ограничить padding и margin

Tags: reactjs

Здаравствуйте, мне стало интересно возможно ли в react ограничить количество отступов.
Например я создаю рекурсивно картинки и картинка создается под родительской картинкой
как то так:

```
{picture}
    {picture}
        {picture}
            {picture}
                {picture}
                    {picture}
```

И эсли их будет много то в какой то момент уйдут за край монитора, как в react'e можно ограничить такое?

P.S я пробовал сам, но у меня вышло это сделать только эсли считать количество картинок и менять стили для последующих картинок

Comment: Просто напишите формулу, которая будет рассчитывать паддинг для картинок.

Comment: @MrYogurt можно пример или ссылку где такое есть?

Answer (score 1):

Никто не догадается здесь, какая формула вам нужна, вы даже код не показали. Но выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
const pictures = ["one", "two"]

const Component = () => {

const calcPadding = 50 / pictures.length // будет высчитываться при каждом ререндере

return <div style={{padding: calcPadding}} />
}
```